# K-Nearest Neighbor - how many reference points/features?

Tags: machine-learning, knn, processing-efficiency, supervised-learning

I want to use KNN to create a training model (I will use other ML models as well), but i'm just wondering...

I have around 6 features, with a total of let's say 60.000 (60 thousand) reference points (so, I have around 10.000 reference points per feature).

I know that this is, from a computational point of view, not ideal (for an algorithm like KNN), so should I use for example KD-Trees (or is KNN okay for this number of features/reference points)?
Because.. if I have to calculate the distance between my test point and *all* the reference points (with for example Euclidean distance, for a multi-dimensional model)..... I can imagine that it will take quite some time..?

I know that other (supervised) ML algorithms are maybe more efficient, but KNN is only one of the algorithms I will use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time complexity of (naive) KNN would be `O(kdn)` where `d` is the dimensionality which is 6 in your case, and `n` is the number of points, which is 60,000 in your case.

Meanwhile, building a KD tree from `n` points is `O(dnlogn)`, with subsequent nearest-neighber lookups taking `O(klogn)` time. This is definitely much better: you sacrifice a little bit of time upfront to build the KD tree, but each KNN lookup later is much faster.

This is all under the assumption that your points are distributed in a "nice" way (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Degradation_in_performance_when_the_query_point_is_far_from_points_in_the_k-d_tree for more details). If they aren't distributed in a "nice" way, then KNN in general might not be the way to go.